# Making faceted line charts with errorbands (aka Trellis charts with confidence intervals) in Vega-Lite.jl

Tags: julia, vega-lite

I have a dataset of the following format, with a price index and a confidence interval (lower and upper) for each date:

```
 Row │ borough   house_class  index    ci₀      ci₁      dates
     │ String15  String7      Float64  Float64  Float64  Date
─────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ Queens    SFH          1.0      1.0      1.0      2003-03-31
   2 │ Queens    SFH          1.10301  1.13093  1.07645  2003-06-30
   3 │ Queens    SFH          1.17184  1.2096   1.13636  2003-09-30
   4 │ Queens    SFH          1.23384  1.28435  1.18716  2003-12-31
   5 │ Queens    SFH          1.28346  1.34361  1.22847  2004-03-31
```

I can successfully create a line plot with the below Vega Lite code for the entire city:

```
idx |>
@vlplot(x=:dates) +
@vlplot(:line,
   y={
        :index,
        title="NYC Price Index",
        scale= {zero = false }
    },
) +
@vlplot(mark=:errorband,
    y=:ci₀,
    y2=:ci₁,
    x="dates")
```

[image: Basic chart]

Now I would like to expand this to chart to be multi-faceted, by `borough` and by `house_class`.

The line part works great by just adding a `row` and `column` but I can't get it to work with my confidence interval error bands.

```
idxb |>
@vlplot(x=:dates, 
    :line,
   y={
        :index,
        title="NYC Price Index",
        scale= {zero = false }
    },
    row=:borough,
    column=:house_class
)
```

[image]

When I try this:

```
idxb |>
@vlplot(x=:dates) +
@vlplot(:line,
   y={
        :index,
        title="NYC Price Index",
        scale= {zero = false }
    },
) +
@vlplot(mark=:errorband,
    row=:borough,
    column=:house_class,
    y=:ci₀,
    y2=:ci₁,
    x="dates")
```

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/ilya/.julia/artifacts/5cc2ca447001163b90bb24e24a389e4f7b0f1e88/vg2svg.js:42:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `facet` and inside its `spec` use `layer`, for example something like:

```
data |> @vlplot(facet = {row = {field = "x1"}},
                 spec = {
                 layer = [
                    {mark = :point, x = :x2, y = :x3},
                     {mark = :line, x = :x2, y = :x3}
                 ]
                 }
                 )
```